# Symfony2 SwiftMailer doesn't send

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a Linux server with SMTP relay configured. Using the command "mail test@test.com" it works but when I use SwiftMailerBundle, no mail is sent.

Logs :

```
[2014-03-14 10:01:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2014-03-14 10:01:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2014-03-14 10:01:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
```

Parameters.yml :

```
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: myusername
mailer_password: ********
```

My command :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class AbsenceCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('absence:absence')
            ->setDescription('Envoi des absences aux parents')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('noreply@test.com')
            ->setTo('mymail@test.com')
            ->setBody("Test")
        ;

        $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);

        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');

        $transport = $mailer->getTransport();
        if ($transport instanceof \Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport) {
            $spool = $transport->getSpool();
            $sent = $spool->flushQueue($this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.transport.real'));
        }

        $output->writeln("E-mail envoyé aux parents des apprentis !");
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on the solution ?

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

try to install postfix mail server.
use this command to install postfix:sudo apt-get install postfix

Comment: What is it ? I don't have admin rights on this server.

Comment: @Servietsky: In that case, chances are you've already have mail server installed. Try connecting to you server via Outlook, Thunderbird or any other to make sure your mailer service is up and listening and that  your credentials work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the **mailer_transport:**  parameter value. try setting it to **mailer_transport:  smtp**.

Comment: so did i, not working, mine is defaulted to smtp already. note, i just did a composer update before i got this error, it did update swift mailer.  ` - Removing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.1.0) - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.2.0)`  any solution yet?